# php post superglobal array doesn't contain all keys from form

Tags: php, forms

I have this html form in my php script

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div style="width: 30em;">

    <label for="firstName">First name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""/>

    <label for="lastName">Last name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""/>

    <label for="password1">Choose a password *</label>
    <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" value=""/>
    <label for="password2">Retype password *</label>
    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" value=""/>

    <label>Your gender: *</label>
    <label for="genderMale">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender1" id="genderMale" value="M" />
    <label for="genderFemale">Female</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="F" />

    <label for="favoriteWidget">What's your favorite widget? *</label>
    <select name="favoriteWidget" id="favoriteWidget" size="1">
        <option value="superWidget">The SuperWidget</option>
        <option value="megaWidget">The MegaWidget</option>
        <option value="wonderWidget">The WonderWidget
        </option>
    </select>

    <label for="newsletter">Do you want to receive our newsletter?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="yes"/>

    <label for="comments">Any comments?</label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

    <div style="clear: both;">
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Send Details"/>
        <input type="reset" name="resetButton" id="resetButton" value="Reset Form" style="margin-right: 20px;"/>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Problem is when i submit my form and run this php code:

```
if ( isset($_POST["submitButton"]) ) {
     echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';  
}
```

I get the following results:

```
Array
(
    [firstName] => 
    [lastName] => 
    [password1] => 
    [password2] => 
    [favoriteWidget] => superWidget
    [comments] => 
    [submitButton] => Send Details
)
```

Most noticeably the gender and newsletter keys in the $_POST array are missing?
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: If checkbox is not checked - it;s not passed to server. Same to radio.

Comment: @u_mulder, how do you prevent it from throwing a notice error, when performing validation, that is if either the radio or checkbox are not checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All checkboxes are boolean for browsers.
This is not about PHP but HTML.

to verify that the person chose newsletter field, try this:

```
$_POST['newsletter'] = isset($_POST['newsletter']) ? $_POST['newsletter'] : 'no';
```

This force your **$_POST** set newsletter when form not checked!

**isset()** verify if your variable exists, then put default value else 'no' for this value.

you can use **array_key_exists()** instead of isset().

```
$_POST['newsletter'] = array_key_exists('newsletter', $_POST) ? $_POST['newsletter'] : 'no';
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on that